# Connecting to the internet without ssh

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, dns

I am studying in Germany and renting an apartment in university accommodation. The apartment comes with internet. The internet setup is very unique and maybe just utilized in German student accommodations.

Essentially accessing the internet involves 2 major steps.

- The 1st step is configuration of the network connection (configure the IP address, subnet mask, gateway/router and DNS server). It involved changing my settings in my WiFi router from dynamic to static and entering a set of personal connection data which was given to me.
- The 2nd step is authentication at login server ( authentication will be established using the ssh command in a terminal window).

There are numerous issues with this setup and I loathe it.

I would like a work around so that I can just connect in the normal way, that is without using the ssh just through my WiFi router. I know it is possible because I stayed in an Airbnb in the same student apartment block which had it set up that way. However, I do not know how to set it up. Could someone please help with this?

Comment: This seems highly unusual and U don't believe it has to do with German ISPs. Please provide further information related to what SSH is doing, as this could be anything and the key may be to find a way to do it without SSH or to get dd-wrt on a router and make perform the SSH stuff automatically.

Comment: That is not a standard way of connecting.  I wonder if your friends dorm is bypassing the problem by connecting via WIFI (ie Wireless ISP mode) instead, or if they have a connection which bypasses the Uni altogether.

Comment: When you use ssh to log in, do you have a window you can type things into?   (If you understand the question, are you able to set up a key based login rather then password based login?  If you can do this then, with the help of dd-wrt you can probably use autossh - otherwise its A LOT harder to do.)

Comment: I assume this is a network administrated by the university not a regular ISP (and for that it's a regular setup). The AirBnB probable did setup the connection as described and just shared the established connection. Although I doubt they used the universities network, they might just have had a different internet connection altogether. It's very doubtful that you'll get around the additional authentification, but you might be able to automate it.

Comment: Try running `ssh` as usual, but add the the "-vvv" option to make ssh print debugging output. Then [edit] your question to include the debugging output. This would show what ssh is doing here and what would be needed to automate it.

Comment: davidgo, I don't believe they are bypassing the university system because there Easybox wifi router is connected to the ethernet cables coming from the outlet. Also you can not allowed to have a 3rd party service so we all have to the service they provide (that is unless you had something like a mobile broadband service). I'm not sure if I can set up a key based login. I suspect not because the only thing I have is a password.

Comment: Kenster, the output from the debug is long I will break it down into multiple comments

Comment: Kenster, actually the output from the debug is too long to post and seems to contain several passwords or keys. I'm not sure if I am allowed to post it. As near as I can tell it is just authenticating my password and computer.

Comment: Albin, it is possible that the Airbnb host were using a different connection though I don't believe that to be the case. While I was there I accidentally turned off their router and didn't realize it until I saw that I had lost the signal. I noticed that their router was connected to the apartment's ethernet outlet. The only service that runs using that outlet is the one by the university well actually the Studentwerke (which is the organization that provides the apartments and services).

Comment: @SnarkyWatersAhead everything is possible but at this point it's just speculation. I would just ask the Airbnb host. Other then then, please note my answer.

Comment: Ok just throwing this out there after looking though some German computer forums. Mind you I have know idea how the following works. Is it possible to accomplish what I want by somehow connecting an access point up to the router or possibly the other war around.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider this a comment, but it's just to extensive, so I post this as an answer:

Although they might be uncommon they are all regular security setting, might be a overambitious network engineer, but after some major attack on Universities in Germany this is understandable:

- Static IP instead of DHCP: less usability but more security
- "Personal Connection Data": first level of authentication (I assume this is the PPP login data?)
- SSH another level of (encrypted) authentication possibly to ensure s.th. that can not be ensured by the first level of authentication

You should simply ask at the "Rechenzentrum", "Studentenwerk" or "Stupa" for ways with easier access (maybe a client or somthing exists).

This being said, these authentications are possibly there for a very good reason. If you don't how to get around it you probable should do it or at least not ask for it so bluntly in a public forum. And there are still liability issues etc. you should consider.

In my own University time I encountered similar setups from a few universities in Germany. Possibly the same admin being let go for his paranoia ;)

I would suggest to address the "numerous issues" themselves (in separate questions), it might be possible to solve them, without going around the networks security.